# Изменение разрешения видео axet/vget

Tags: java, youtube

Здравствуйте, девелоперы, снова! Вчера я задавал вопрос насчет загрузки видео с YouTube. Ответы получил, но в конце-концов они не помогли. Но не суть. Нашел я просто обалденную библиотеку для этого дела - https://github.com/axet/vget. Все качает, все прекрасно, но проблема вот в чем: не могу изменить разрешение видео. В [wiki](https://github.com/axet/vget) в [данном](https://github.com/axet/vget#example-application-managed-download) разделе написано в коде, как это делать, но ничего не получается. Возможно, кто-нибудь работал с этой библиотекой и может подсказать, как его изменить?